# Why literal does not match format string exception in JPA while saving Date Field

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have some Date fields in Oracle but i kept it as String in Entity Class. Except one field all other fields are saving correctly . For one field i am getting an error as

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.
```

Just before calling the save function in JPA i see the values exactly matching with the values which are saving correctly . Not sure what else can debug or how i can fix it .
Below are the values just before calling save .

```
paymentDate=2013-03-04 16:30:07,
noteDate   =2013-03-04 16:30:07,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using To_Date `TO_DATE(dateStr, formatStr)` may solve your problem.

if your table column data type is String then you should typecast to a string before saving it to your database.